# CSS remove table tr space or margin

Tags: html, css, html-table

I can't make it to 0 margin/padding.

This is the pic:

[image]

You can see the red oval is the problem.
I want to make it to 0 margin but I don't know where is the problem.

This is my HTML CODE:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="share">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="img/sector/Insta-4.jpg" width="100%"></td>
                <td><img src="img/sector/Insta-3.jpg" width="100%"></td>
                <td><img src="img/sector/Insta-2.jpg" width="100%"></td>
                <td><img src="img/sector/Insta-1.jpg" width="100%"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="img/sector/Insta-8.jpg" width="100%"></td>
                <td><img src="img/sector/Insta-7.jpg" width="100%"></td>
                <td><img src="img/sector/Insta-6.jpg" width="100%"></td>
                <td><img src="img/sector/Insta-5.jpg" width="100%"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
.content { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; }
.share table { width: 100%; border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 0; }
.share table td { padding: 0; margin: 0; width: 25%; }
```

I've tried with border-collapse: collapse but didn't work as well. 
And also with ul li, but gives me the same problem maybe worst.

Comment: display:block on image

Comment: definitely a duplicate. In short, add `vertical-align: middle;` to `.share table td img` - or `display:block;` as mentioned above